# Is the Gboard's `emoji fast-access row` functional?

Tags: android, keyboard, emoji, gboard

I have tried enabling it from the `Emojis, stickers and GIFs` section with no luck so far.
It works however nicely on `Youtube`, `Whatssap`, among other messaging apps. So, what I'm not sure if this is open, or you have to register your app somewhere. I have also tried with multiple `TextInput/EditText` configurations.